# Powershell StreamWriter limit

Tags: powershell, sockets

I have to send 130MB of data via a TCP Socket. When I export the data to a file like above then I have all data. But when I try send via socket then it send about 65% data.

Is any Stream limitations? Or what can be wrong?

To a file:

```
$global:arrResults |  Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test.txt' -Encoding UTF8
```

Via a socket:

```
try{$connection=New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($PC, $PORT) -ErrorAction Stop}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to set up the connection with $PC on port $PORT"; exit 2}
$stream=$connection.GetStream()
$writer=New-Object -Type System.IO.StreamWriter($stream)
foreach($line in $global:arrResults)
{
    $writer.WriteLine($line)
}

$writer.Close()
$connection.Close()
```

PS. I send the data to Splunk.

Comment: Can you send smaller files without any issues? Have you tried `flush()`ing the stream?

Comment: I do not have problem with smaller data set. I have not tried flushing.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 0):

When I split the StreamWriter into multiple smaller data sets then it sends all.

I had about 320 000 lines in the stream.

I am going to investigate where is the limit.